# How to isolate a React Navigation Tab in standalone comopnent?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to separate my navigation tabs into an isolated folder called `tabs`.

The first tab called `HomeTab`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

import {Home} from '../../../screens';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const HomeTab = () => (
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
        <Icon name="home" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
);

export {HomeTab};
```

I imported my `HomeTab` and nested with `TabNavigator`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {HomeTab} from './Tabs/Home';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigation = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <HomeTab />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
export default TabNavigation;
```

**But I got this error:**

[image]

However, when I move the `HomeTab` code inside the `TabNavigator`, it works as expected.

```js
const TabNavigation = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Icon name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

[image]

Comment: If the answer bellow helped, please consider mark your question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Direct `children` of any `react-navigation` parent must be a `Group`, a `Screen` or a `Fragment`, consider doing this:

```js
const TabNavigation = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <HomeTab />
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

```js
const HomeTab = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <Icon name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
   
    {* any other tab *}

  </Tab.Navigator>
);
```